# EkinoWordpressBundle assest path configuration

Tags: wordpress, symfony

I try setup https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle 
i do all from setup manual, site work but asset have wrong  paths

example i have in symfony2 twig template

```
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

in rendered source i see it as

```
<script src="/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData"></script>
```

or direct

```
<img src="/bundles/mybundle/img/test.jpg">
```

for / is real path

```
/symfony/web/bundles/mybundle/img/test.jpg
```

so it don`t work. Page structure from manual is

```
/
/symfony
/symfony/web
/index.php
```

i don`t found concept in bundle authors manual,

i should add something to htacces or is possible to configure this in symfony config ?

here is proposed .htacces

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
IndexIgnore /symfony

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just also answered to this question on the Github issue (https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle/issues/77) but I will also answer here as some people should be interested in the response.

I see at least 2 ways to solve this problem.

#### 1 - Create symlinks on your assets directories

The simple way will be to add symlinks on your (Wordpress) root directory to the `symfony/web/js` and `symfony/web/bundles` for instance:

```
$ ln -s symfony/web/js js
$ ln -s symfony/web/bundles bundles
```

#### 2 - Override the Symfony assets UrlPackage class

You can override the base url used by the Symfony assets management by overriding the `Symfony\Component\Templating\Asset\UrlPackage` class.

Create a new custom class:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Templating\Asset;

use Symfony\Component\Templating\Asset\UrlPackage as BaseUrlPackage;

/**
 * UrlPackage
 */
class UrlPackage extends BaseUrlPackage
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBaseUrl($path)
    {
        $baseUrl = parent::getBaseUrl($path);

        return sprintf('/symfony/%s', $baseUrl);
    }
}
```

and then define the new class into the appropriate parameter in your `config.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    templating.asset.url_package.class: Acme\DemoBundle\Templating\Asset\UrlPackage
```

Maybe we could add this `UrlPackage` class into the bundle. Do you feel ok to submit us a pull request to integrate it with a new bundle configuration entry?

Otherwise, I will try to implement it as soon as possible.

Hope it helps.

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Thank You. I think symlinks is good idea - templates can have static links to media in this way it work without problems.